# generate Icon with svg content

Tags: java, swing, svg, batik

I want to generate an icon with an svg icon content. For example a yellow circle with a face (svg file) in it. At the moment I have this code.

1. The circle is in the right position but the svg is drawn all over the JPanel and if i resize the frame the svg is added all the time.
2. The svg is loaded with white background and in the wrong size.

Is there a way to make the background of the svg transparent and transform the svg to the circle size?

As information: The svg file has got a transparent background (seen in adobe illustrator) but in Java its loaded white...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import org.apache.batik.swing.JSVGCanvas;

public class IconTest extends JPanel{

    public IconTest(){

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        super.paintComponent(g2d);
        this.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // create icon body
        Ellipse2D iconBody = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 100, 100);
        g2d.setPaint(Color.YELLOW);
        g2d.draw(iconBody);
        g2d.fill(iconBody);

        // icon content
        JSVGCanvas svg = new JSVGCanvas();
        svg.setURI("file:/C:/Users/Linda/Desktop/smile.svg");
        add(svg);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("IconTest");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600,600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        IconTest i = new IconTest();
        frame.add(i);


    }
}
```

edit:

bevor transforming the window size

[image]

after transforming the window size. The SVG is added all the time with white background and it's size depends on how fast i transform the window...

[image]

Edit: You can download the svg file [here](http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/emoticon-square-smiling-face-with-closed-eyes_42734)

Answer (score 2):

> The svg is loaded with white background and in the wrong size.

I'm not 100% sure 'cause I can't test atm, but you're adding a white background with:

```
this.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255)); //Remove this line
```

So, the background is white and that's why you're seeing the svg with white background. Or change it to another color and see what happens.

What do you mean with `in the wrong size`?

> The circle is in the right position but the svg is drawn all over the JPanel and if i resize the frame the svg is added all the time.

Well, `JFrame` by default has a [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) and the default position when you add something without specifying where in the `BorderLayout` you want it is [`BorderLayout.CENTER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#CENTER) and you're not adding anything else to it anywhere, so it's using the 100% size of your `JPanel`. Maybe you'd want to try with a different [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for example a [BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) or [FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) or maybe a [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).

Another thing I saw in your code is you're adding your `IconTest` panel AFTER you're showing your `JFrame`, instead you should change it like this, once you've chosen another Layout for your `JFrame`.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("IconTest");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
IconTest i = new IconTest();
frame.add(i);
frame.setSize(600,600);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: 1.) this.setBackground(...) is for the Panel. If i remove it or change it the background of the SVG is still white and not transparent 2.) Do i need the Layout? Is there no way to tell Java to place the SVG at position(x,y) ? 3.) I'll add my result above.

Comment: @Linda which IDE are you using?

Comment: I using Eclipse Kepler. Do not thing that my IDE is the problem?!

Comment: @Linda I don't know, I'm just asking to replicate run the code under the same environment :)

Comment: @Linda can you upload your svg file too?